# vb.net How can i kill the application that i created using createObject()

Tags: vb.net, createobject

I'm using `CreateObject(progId)` in Vb to create a `pdfDOcument`.
But the problem is that after i'm done and closing the document and release, How can I shutdown the process?

How can I reference the process and know if it was already open by the user before I created the object? And how can I kill the process if the process was not running before I created the object (`pdfDocument`)?

Is there better strategies than to use `CreateObject()`?

Comment: CreateObject does not create an application/process.  It just instantiates an automation object with the ProgID.  That's probably why you didn't get any help.  The question is really about the "AcroExch" wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that we've found is to create the application object before we create any application's object.

For example:

```
dim objApp as object = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
dim objDoc as Object = CreateObject("AcroExch.document")

...
objApp.CloseAllDocuments()

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objApp)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objDoc)
```

But next time I will never use `CreateObject`. 
I'll try to use framework classes (especially the `Runtime` and `Reflection` for such examples).